# Why does my function not execute when the condition is met?

Tags: python, function, recursion, counter

I'm trying to make a login form for my server application and have stumbled onto an invisible error (the worst kind). I have a **tries** variable that increments by 1 every time the user enters the username incorrectly. When the **tries** variable reaches **3**, the program should then execute the **block()** function. My issue is that it doesn't.

All my .txt files are blank so there's not an error there and everything seems fine. Please help because I'm pulling my hair out!

Here's the code:

```
import socket
import time
import sys
import os

tries = 0

def server():

    def block():

        #get host ip
        ipBlock = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        #create black list
        ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "w")
        ipBlackList.close()

        #read black list
        ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "r")
        isBlocked = ipBlackList.readlines()
        ipBlackList.close()

        #disable account for 60 seconds
        if ipBlock in isBlocked:
            def countdown(t):
                while t:
                    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
                    timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
                    print('Your account has been temporarily disabled. Please 
                    try again in '+timer, end=" seconds.\r")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    t -= 1
                    os.remove('ipBlackList.txt')
                    print('\nYour account has been re-enabled. You may log in 
                    now.')
                    time.sleep(2)
                t = 60
                countdown(int(t))
    block()

    print("Enter administrator login details: ")

    def usernameLogin():
        #global vars
        global tries

        if tries == 3:
            #read black list
            ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "r")
            isBlocked = ipBlackList.readlines()
            ipBlackList.close()

            #get host ip
            ipBlock = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

            if ipBlock not in isBlocked:
                ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "w")
                ipBlackList.write(ipBlock)
                ipBlackList.close()
                block()

        username = input("\nUsername: ")

        #check if username exists
        usernames = open("usernames.txt", "r")
        checkUser = usernames.readlines()
        usernames.close()

        if username not in checkUser:
            print("That username doesn't exist. Please try again.")
            tries += 1
            print(tries)
            time.sleep(2)
            usernameLogin()

        print("im in")
        time.sleep(3)

    usernameLogin()
server()
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with your indenting? From what I can tell, your program does nothing except `print("Enter administrator login details: ")`.

Comment: @quamrana yeah, everything is indented as it should. I just rushed pasting in the code when writing the question because I needed to be somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. You need to provide a [mre]. To start, the code you posted has a syntax error

Comment: @wjandrea OK, I've edited my code with what I believe to be the proper indentation. Please check my code again and notify me of any new or existing errors I may have.

Comment: @c1ph3r It now has two syntax errors. It seems like something is wrapping your code at 80 characters. As well, `sys` is not used and the line `countdown(int(t))` seems to be over-indented. Are you sure this is minimal? It's a lot of code for a relatively simple problem. To start, the files seem to be irrelevant; for the sake of example you could use global lists.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code do execute the `block()` function when `tries==3`, but in the begining of the `block()` you recreate the black list file, then you read the empty file and as a result the condition `if ipBlock in isBlocked:` is always false.

So, I've placed the commands that create the file out of the `block()`.  Also, I've changed the `remove` of the black list file in the `countdown()` function and recreate but not delete it, because your code try to read it again when restarts to ask the username. Also I've set `tries == 0` when `block()` ends. Also, the indentation at the end of `countdown()` was incorrect.

```
import socket
import time
import sys
import os

tries = 0

def server():

    def block():

        #get host ip
        ipBlock = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        #read black list
        ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "r")
        isBlocked = ipBlackList.readlines()
        ipBlackList.close()

        #disable account for 60 seconds

        if ipBlock in isBlocked:
            def countdown(t):
                while t:
                    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
                    timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
                    print('Your account has been temporarily disabled. Please \
                    try again in '+timer, end=" seconds.\r")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    t -= 1

                #os.remove('ipBlackList.txt')
                # Recreate an empty black list file
                ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "w")
                ipBlackList.close()

                print('\nYour account has been re-enabled. You may log in \
                now.')
                time.sleep(2)
            t = 6
            countdown(int(t))

    #create black list file (empty)
    ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "w")
    ipBlackList.close()
    block()

    print("Enter administrator login details: ")

    def usernameLogin():
        #global vars
        global tries

        if tries == 3:
            #read black list
            ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "r")
            isBlocked = ipBlackList.readlines()
            ipBlackList.close()

            #get host ip
            ipBlock = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
            if ipBlock not in isBlocked:
                ipBlackList = open("ipBlackList.txt", "w")
                ipBlackList.write(ipBlock)
                ipBlackList.close()
                block()

            tries = 0

        username = input("\nUsername: ")

        #check if username exists
        usernames = open("/test/usernames.txt", "r")
        checkUser = usernames.readlines()
        usernames.close()

        if username not in checkUser:
            print("That username doesn't exist. Please try again.")
            tries += 1
            print(tries)
            time.sleep(2)
            usernameLogin()

        print("im in")
        time.sleep(3)

    usernameLogin()
server()
```